# TRANSFORM ROW WISE DATA INTO ONE COLUMN CONSECUTIVELY based on the number of values in each row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-filter

I've learned how to use filters to organize row-wise data into columns and am taking that to heart in this spreadsheet!  But I've hit a major snag.

If you look at the example I've attached here, you'll see that I've successfully built out columns S through X - and everything is working with either filtering or SQL queries to data located elsewhere in this workbook - some from this sheet, some from other sheets . and it all aligns perfectly!

But here's the problem.  As you can see in columns Z through AG, the answers to each survey columns are arrayed row-wise.   When I try to filter columnns AA through AG and place the results in column V, I run into two problems: 1) it stacks everything from AA, then AB, then AC etc.   That's exactly wrong!  I need it to stack Row 3's values from AA through AD as I have done in V3 through V6.  But the problem is that I haven't figured out how to do this using an array formula - and the numbers of answer options for each question differ - anywhere from 2 to 7.  I've got a helper column in Z which shows how many data points there are per question - and I was hoping to get that to operate as a control to determine how many datapoints I would need to write into column V.   Couldn't figure that one out.  So - I wrote a ridiculous formula to process the control in column Z in order to determine how many cells (from 1 to 7, AA to AG) to write out, transposed.  But then, I can't do that in a single column using ARRAYFORMULA - which defeats the entire effort.

Everywhere you see a light green cell, there's a formula in there.

So - here are the formulas:

**Column S** (easy enough):
*`=query($O3:$Q,"select O where O > 0 order by O asc", 0)`*

**Column T** (also easy enough):
*`=arrayformula(if(isblank($S3:S),"",if($S3:$S<>$S2:$S,vlookup($S3:$S,ExitPollSETUP!$C28:$E,{2,3},false),"")))`*
---this is a simple breakpoint tool to only label the first row in each group so the labels don't repeat (and it also pulls in column U).

I'll jump over **Column V** for a second - that's the "problem area".

**Column W** and **X** are simple queries retrieving already-filtered data which matches up correctly with Column S.  (I've validated all of this and it's working perfectly).
**Here's that formula:**
*`=query($O3:$Q,"select P,Q where O > 0 order by O asc", 0)`*

Now - for **Column V** - you can see that I want to fit in exactly the columns AA through AG, transposed into a single column, but only based on the number of answers, which is the control in **Column Z**.  I want to do this recursively so that it all falls in as shown in the document.  But I couldn't figure out how to do that in an array formula - which is the big problem I'm having - so instead I've had to **paste in the same dumb formula for each new question** and that's exaclty what I don't want to do!

Here's the formula currently being used for each answer in **Column V**:
*`=if($T3<>"",IF($Z3=7,transpose($AA3:$AG3),if($Z3=6,transpose($AA3:$AF6),if($Z3=5,transpose($AA3:$AE3),if($Z3=4,transpose($AA3:$AD3),if($Z3=3,transpose($AA3:$AC3),if($Z3=2,transpose($AA3:$AB3),"")))))),"")`*

See what I'm doing here?  Selecting the number of cells to transform using the helper column.

So - bottom line - how can I go a row at a time through the entire set of **AA** to **AG** and then transpose all of it - left to right per row, and continue moving through the data left to right per row, and place it correctly in the first row of each answer, in **Column V** ????

I'm bewildered by this - and would LOVE an answer.  Thanks for reading this.

Gary K.

(BTW-I'm running this with an API query to a highly secure data set and can't share the sheet because the data is being generated with a KEY.  That's why I've cut out a sample of the sheet and pasted it here and provided the relevant formulas above)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula takes each question and its standard answers in a single row, and re-formats the data to the desired output.

`=query({query({A:I},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4");query({A:I},"select Col1,' ','  ', Col5 where Col5 is not null LABEL ' ' '', '  ' ''",0);query({A:I},"select Col1,' ','  ',Col6 where Col6 is not null LABEL ' ' '', '  ' ''",0);query({A:I},"select Col1,' ','  ',Col7 where Col7 is not null LABEL ' ' '', '  ' ''",0);query({A:I},"select Col1,' ','  ',Col8 where Col8 is not null LABEL ' ' '', '  ' ''",0)},"where Col1 is not NULL order by Col1")`

---

- The query is nested, each additional response separated by an array separator (`;`)
- For the second and subsequent responses, there is a "where" to test for the existence of the response.
- The formula (as written) assumes that the maximum number of responses = 6.
  But if the maximum is (or becomes) greater than 6, then it is a simple matter to add an extra query into the nested array.

---

**SAMPLE**

[image]

---

Comment: Hi.  Thanks so much for sending me your very helpful and logical code.  Fascinating, really.  Problem: I'm getting an array literal error.

Here's a link to the spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZQl4B0wpER8WbQpzfmn4ZxT86cPQA7ewjsZVRj1ZgpM/edit?usp=sharing

Please, if you can, take a look at the last sheet, **Filter2**.  The code you provided is in **L2**.  The four red columns are intended to be where the output of the nexted query is written.

Thanks so much!  -Gary

Comment: Perhaps you mean "FILTER:T2" BUT... just had to refresh json on "ExitPollSETUP". Note: your formula in "ExitPollSETUP!C27" is a bit convoluted. Refer my simplified formula `=if($B$6=true,transpose(importJSON($B$4,if($B$7=true,B5,""))),"Don't load JSON")` (using checkboxes) on "tedinozJSON".

Comment: Note:, Q#2074 has 13 responses so you need to expand the formula  by adding Col13, Col14, Col15 & Col16. Refer sheet="tedinozFilter:T2" for an example.

Comment: This is all incredibly helpful.  Wow!  And thanks for catching my error on filtering an insufficient quantity of columns.  I actually thought it was my DATA filter that was wrong producing the mismatch - and was digging around - not realizing that it was actually the questions and answers where I had come up short.

Comment: You have saved me with this - can't tell you how much I appreciate your guidance!

Comment: No worries - [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)